# How to view contents of append query

Tags: ms-access, append

I am attempting to review the contents of an append query in MS Access, however, attempting to review through:

[image]

does not open anything.

How can I review the contents of an append query:

Comment: Have you tried doing a Compact and Repair Database?

Comment: That did not work

Comment: It is possible the Append Query is written in SQL too complicated to be displayed visually. try to see it in SQL view.

Comment: @SunKnight0 that does not work either

Comment: Does the query actually work?

Comment: @SunKnight0 How can I tell that? attempting to run, notes the errror of file refference

Comment: If it worked I would say there is some weird security lock I didn't know about but if it errors out when run it is probably empty or corrupt. If Compact and Repair didn't work I think you are out of luck.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Is there anyway to undo the corruption of a query?

Comment: Compact and Repair is the only way I know. Unless you have backups/old versions of the database.

Comment: New thought: Is this a standalone database? If it links to other databases/files and it has been moved (or the linked files have been moved) that could also be the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124461/discussion-between-sauron-and-sunknight0).

Comment: I attempted to run and the error appeared: F:\....  is not a valid file path. It appears the file paths are out of sync. If I cannot review the query, how can I change the file path?

Comment: @SunKnight0 how can I update all linked table reference programmatically?

Comment: There is no "Update all linked tables" function. You have to delete the linked tables and re-link them one by one or by creating a linked tables table and looping through it.